# Filling in missing value with probabilities

Tags: pandas

Say giving a columns fruit, I have 57 banana, 54 apple, and other Null values.
Now I want to fill the null value with `fillna` with the probability of which 57/(57+54) probability as banana, and  54/(57+54) as apple, how should I do it?

```
Fruit
------
None
Banana
Fruit
Banana
....(with 57 banana, 54 apple, 10 None)
```

Comment: Can you add sample and desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***setup***

```
fruit = pd.Series(['banana'] * 57 + ['apple'] * 54 + [None] * 10, name='fruit')
```

---

***using `pd.Series.sample`***

```
nullfruit = fruit.isnull()
fruit.loc[nullfruit] = fruit.dropna().sample(nullfruit.sum()).values
```

***using `np.random.choice` and `np.unique`***

```
nullfruit = fruit.isnull().values
u, c = np.unique(fruit.values[~nullfruit], return_counts=1)

fruit.loc[nullfruit] = np.random.choice(u, nullfruit.sum(), p=c / c.sum())
```