# Filling missing values with probability based on another attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill missing values based on probability distribution from known instances with condition from another attribute. Specifically:

```
Weather_Conditions         | Road_Surface | Date_Month
----------
Fine without high winds    | NaN          | 9
Fine without high winds    | NaN          | 1
Raining without high winds | Wet/Damp     | 6
Fine without high winds    | Wet/Damp     | 1
Fine without high winds    | NaN          | 2
Fine without high winds    | NaN          | 1
Raining without high winds | Wet/Damp     | 7
Raining without high winds | Wet/Damp     | 1
```

If month is January, all missing Road_Surface values should be filled with ratio 1:3 Frost:Wet.

So far I managed to create array of values to-be-filled with

```
road_values_jan = np.random.choice(["Frost/Ice", "Wet/Damp"], random_data["Road_Surface_Conditions"][random_data['Date_Month'].isin(["01"])].isnull().sum(), p=[0.25, 0.75])

# which outputs:
array(['Wet/Damp', 'Frost/Ice'], dtype='<U9')
```

The issue comes when I want it to bind it to original dataframe. I tried

```
null_road = random_data["Road_Surface_Conditions"][random_data['Date_Month'].isin(["01"])].isnull()

random_data.loc['null_road'] = np.random.choice(road_values_jan, road_values_jan.size)
```

from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824794/filling-in-missing-value-with-probabilities) , but it says: *ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns*

I also played with

```
random_data["Road_Surface_Conditions"][random_data['Date_Month'].isin(["01"])] = random_data["Road_Surface_Conditions"][random_data['Date_Month'].isin(["01"])].fillna(pandas.Series(road_values_jan, index=random_data.index))
```

but this one gives me *ValueError: Length of passed values is 2, index implies 8*

How can I this two-value array append to NaN values under Month condition?

Please do find .csv-style data below:

```
Weather_Conditions,Road_Surface_Conditions,Date_Month
Fine without high winds,NaN,9
Fine without high winds,NaN,1
Raining without high winds,Wet/Damp,6
Fine without high winds,Wet/Damp,1
Fine without high winds,NaN,2
Fine without high winds,NaN,1
Raining without high winds,Wet/Damp,7
Raining without high winds,Wet/Damp,1
```

Comment: Hi MMMaroko, can you put your sample data in a form that can be easily copied and pasted by a potential answerer?

Comment: @ASGM Surely did.

Comment: I tried pasting your solutions, but they rely on a bunch of variables that aren't in your sample (`random_data`, `road_values_jan`, etc.).  It's much easier if I can just copy a whole block of code that re-creates your problem.

Comment: `random_data` is main df, `road_values_jan` is created/defined in my first code block above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, you can first create an array with distribution of 25:75 with the same size of your `NaN` values and then select those rows which are `NaN` in your `Road_Surface_Conditions` column and fill them with the created array:

```
m = (df['Road_Surface_Conditions'].isnull() & df['Date_Month'].eq(1)).sum()

s = np.random.choice(['Frost/Ice', 'Wet/Damp'],
                     p=[0.25, 0.75], 
                     size = m)
print(s)
['Wet/Damp' 'Frost/Ice']
```

---

```
df.loc[df['Road_Surface_Conditions'].isnull() & df['Date_Month'].eq(1), 
       'Road_Surface_Conditions'] = s

print(df)
           Weather_Conditions Road_Surface_Conditions  Date_Month
0     Fine without high winds                     NaN           9
1     Fine without high winds                Wet/Damp           1
2  Raining without high winds                Wet/Damp           6
3     Fine without high winds                Wet/Damp           1
4     Fine without high winds                     NaN           2
5     Fine without high winds               Frost/Ice           1
6  Raining without high winds                Wet/Damp           7
7  Raining without high winds                Wet/Damp           1
```

**Note** my dataframe is called `df` instead of `random_data`

Comment: "select those rows which are NaN in your Road_Surface_Conditions column and fill them with the created array" - but only for those NaN rows, where Date_Month is 1 (Jan). But you filled also 2 and 9 and those have different distribution.

So desired output fills only two NaN (where Month is 1), and keeps other two rows (where Month is 2 and 9) as NaN.

Comment: I see, didn't understand you correctly, see updated answer for correct output @MMMaroko